# Forcing ActiveScaffold to delete association rather than setting foreign key to null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activescaffold

I am using ActiveScaffold in an RoR 2.2 project. I have two models in my app:

```
class Foo << ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar << ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :foos
end
```

When I edit a Bar instance, all the foo instances that belong to that bar are displayed in the form with a Remove button next to each one.

When I remove one and then press the Update button, right now ActiveScaffold sets Foo.bar_id to `nil` and issues and update statement like `UPDATE foo set bar_id = null ...`.

Is there a way to delete association from the database (i.e. `delete foo where foo_id = ...`) instead?

Comment: This is an ActiveScaffold question. It automatically generates a lot of things in the background for you. Right now in the scenario that I've mentioned, delete works by setting the Foo.bar_id to null. I want removing a foo from Bar delete it from the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should achieve the effect you're looking for. Keep in mind I haven't run or tested this code.

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :foos, :dependent => :destroy, :after_remove => :delete_orphan

  def delete_orphan(foo)
    foo.destroy
  end

end
```

**Edit**: Switched to a more specific callback

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in Rails 3.1.

When I delete a Document, all the associated DocumentFoo's are also deleted.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :document_foos

  before_destroy { |record| DocumentFoo.destroy_all "document_id = #{record.id}" }
end
```

Br,
Jonas